# Highcharts - Resizeable y-axis as one for Candlestick & Volume chart

Tags: highcharts, resize, candlestick-chart

Still not finding a solution, I am compelled to post here.

I have a candlestick chart and volume chart from “Highcharts”. Both should be in the same axis. When I resize, both should resize as one. See the image below.
[image]

Currently, Highchart supports it as two panes, which is of no use for me. Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resizing is for axes and series could be assigned to any axis, so if you will have multiple series in the same yAxis then resizing will work for all series in that yAxis.

Default demo data for volume is about `1 000 000` greater than OHLC data, so I have adjusted that in the below demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oegqudbz/

```js
Highcharts.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-ohlcv.json', function (data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]],

        i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] / 1e6 // the volume in milions
        ]);
    }


    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },

        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2,
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        tooltip: {
            split: true
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

There is no limit for how many panes (or yAxes) are possible to change through the draggable-pane module, so you could have more than 2 axes and more than 2 resizers and more than just 2 axes assigned to one resizer. More info in the API reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.resize